# InDesign: how to align paragraph to ascender grid

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, formatting

I would like to align nicely two paragraphs with different sizes together. Currently, aligning them to the baseline creates a disgraceful whitespace on top caused by the different leadings.

What I have:

[image]

What I would like:

[image]

How to align my text to an ascender grid instead of the traditional baseline grid? To put it another way, I would like each paragraph to align starting from the ascenders of its first line.

Comment: If you want to align first line of texts in regard to ascenders, I suggest you just forget about baseline grid. It's just not how it works.

Comment: @Vinny Thanks for your suggestion. The reason I asked is that I'd like to have a grid system based on Muller-Brockmann's principles in which different paragraph styles align nicely by having the leadings multiples of one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> a text box and then in the 'Baseline Options' tab you can set up a 'Custom Baseline Grid' which will ignore the document baseline grid setting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. But unless I miss your point, doing so still aligns the text relative to a (custom) baseline, not to the ascender. As shown in the second image of the post, I would like two different paragraphs to align to the top.

Comment: As Vinny also mentioned, the baseline grid might not be very helpful here. You can try this method, but it's still going to take some manual adjustment. There's no built-in feature to do this alignment automatically.

Comment: Oh I understand your post now. I guess the easiest would be to directly set the leading of the paragraph style and then align it top of the text box and manually do that for each text box? Is the custom baseline still relevant in that case?

Comment: Depends on your document. You haven't mentioned if you have any reasons to keep the main flow of text (shown in larger font) on a baseline grid. Then the custom grid would just add exceptions to the main grid. Then, vertical justification could also work in combination with the custom baseline grid, but this is something you should try yourself as we don't have access to the actual file nor do we know which fonts you are using.

Comment: I found the free-floating option with top alignment to work best in my case. Thanks!